# tempusdominus : datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use tempusdominus to show a date picker with the locales in fr but I have an error : "datetimepicker is not a function" and the icons dosen't show up and also the language in french
does somebody know why please ?

here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/fGsjyDC

my code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2"/>
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                        locale: 'fr'
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include files in **HEAD** in the following order will remove this error

```
<!--Bootstrap CSS CDN-->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Bootstrap JS CDN-->
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Moment JS CDN-->
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<!--Tempusdominus JS CDN-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

<!--Tempusdominus CSS CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
```